# Aeson: how do I parse an object with an element that is a stringified object?

Tags: haskell, aeson

I need to parse an object that has a string element where the string itself is a stringified object:

```
{ 
  "a"   : "apples",
  "bar" : "{\"b\":\"bananas\"}"
}
```

I would like to parse this into `Just ( Foo { fooA = "apples", fooBar = Bar { barB = "bananas" } } )` so if parsing of `bar` returns `Nothing` then the parsing of the whole object returns `Nothing`, ie the result is as though the `bar` element of the object was not stringified.

Here is my attempt in which the parsing of `testData` returns `Nothing`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.Aeson  
import Data.Aeson.Types

data Foo = Foo { fooA :: String
               , fooBar :: Bar
               } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Foo where
  parseJSON (Object o) = do bar <- (o .: "bar")
                            Foo <$> o .: "a" <*> parseJSON bar
  parseJSON x          = typeMismatch "Foo" x

data Bar = Bar { barB :: String
               } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Bar where
  parseJSON (Object o) = Bar <$> o .: "b"
  parseJSON x          = typeMismatch "Bar" x

testData = "{ \"a\":\"apples\", \"bar\":\"{\\\"b\\\":\\\"bananas\\\"}\" }"

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show d
  where d :: Maybe Foo
        d = decode testData
```

How can I modify the above code to perform closer to what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get more insight into what's going on by using:

```
main = print (eitherDecode testData :: Either String Foo)
```

which displays: `Left "Error in $: expected Bar, encountered String"`

In this code:

```
 parseJSON (Object o) = do bar <- (o .: "bar")
                           Foo <$> o .: "a" <*> parseJSON bar
```

`bar` is `String ...` value.

To accomplish what you want to do, you could add a case to the FromJSON instance for Bar to catch this:

```
instance FromJSON Bar where
  ...
  parseJSON (String text) =
    case eitherDecode (textToLBS text) of
      Left  e -> fail $ "while decoding a Bar: " ++ e
      Right b -> return b
  ...
```

Or you could put this code in the parseJSON definition for Foo.

Here `textToLBS` converts strict Text to lazy ByteStrings:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as TE

textToLBS :: T.Text -> LBS.ByteString
textToLBS t = LBS.fromStrict (TE.encodeUtf8 t)
```

Code available at: http://lpaste.net/143183